# What thread does sleep method interrupt?

Tags: java, multithreading

After reading Java doc plus stackoverflow's answers no this question, i came to a thought that `Thread.sleep()` sleeps the current thread. Okay. How do i determine what is the current thread in my case?

When this code runs for the first time, it runs in a default thread which executes the main function. Am i right? So we sleep this thread for a second to allow the others threads to do their stuff.

After the `invokeLater()` is called, we start running the render method from the brand new thread so when we call `Thread.sleep()` the second time, we interrup this new thread while the default one is running without any kind of interruption. Am i missing something here?

The last thing i don't understand is that when i test this code, by calling `Thread.sleep()` it interrupts the whole Swing thing: GUI, events etc. That means that everything that is not Swing related in my program should run absolutely seamlessly but seems like it's not.

```
private void render() {
        if (bs == null) {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            bs = getBufferStrategy();
        }

        g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        onRender(g);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> render());
    }
```

Comment: Sleep is a `static` method and hence, it always interrupts the current thread.

Comment: It doesn't interrupt anything. It sleeps the current thread. It's a static method. It can't do anything else.

Comment: @EJP does render method run in a new runnable that i pass into invokeLater, or in EDT?

Comment: That's answered in the Javadoc. Why are you wasting time here?

Comment: @EJP, When i pass a runnable into invokeLater, i'm creating another thread and use its method run to call that render method. How is that possible? I mean, there is only one thread which is EDT. The EDT somehow uses a queue and after all of the Swing stuff is processed, it executs the run method from the runnable without creating another thread. I just want to understand how it works internally.

Answer (score 1):

> `Thread.sleep()` sleeps the current thread [but] How do i determine what is the current thread?

You misunderstand what "current thread" means.  It means the thread that called the method.

Don't think of `Thread.sleep(n)` as doing anything to a thread.  Think of it as a method that does *nothing*, and then returns `n` milliseconds later.

> When i pass a runnable into invokeLater, i'm creating another thread and use its method run to call that render method. How is that possible?

`invokeLater(r)` puts `r` onto a queue. It also creates the EDT, but only if the EDT does not already exist. So, there will never be more than one EDT. The EDT eventually will pick `r` off the queue and call `r.run()`.

In your case, `r` is created by the lambda expression, `() -> render()`.  Every time your `render()` function is run, it will queue up a new `Runnable()`, and  the EDT will almost immediately call `render()` again.

> When i test this code, by calling Thread.sleep() it interrupts the whole Swing thing

*ALL* events are handled by the EDT.  When the EDT calls your `render()` method, it can't do anything else---it can't handle any events---until `render()` returns.  The `sleep(1000)` call insures that `render()` will not return for at least one full second.  That is one full second during which your program will be unable to respond to any user input.

Since the EDT will be calling your `render()` function more or less continuously, that means that the EDT will spend almost all of its time sleeping, your program will be mostly unresponsive to user input.

Comment: When i pass a runnable into invokeLater, i'm creating another thread and use its method run to call that render method. How is that possible? I mean, there is only one thread which is EDT. The EDT somehow uses a queue and after all of the Swing stuff is processed, it executs the run method from the runnable without creating another thread. I just want to understand how it works internally.

Answer (score 0):

A static invocation of [Thread.sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)...

> Causes the **currently executing thread** to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

(bold statement underlined by me).

If you invoke it in a thread that seems to render some UI (or in general, in the main running thread), you will almost certainly see some degradation in usability.

Note that the concepts of a thread sleeping and interrupting a thread are different.

That's why you need to catch `InterruptedException` when invoking `Thread.sleep`, as the thread might be interrupted while sleeping, e.g. by another thread invoking `interrupt` on the sleeping thread.

Also note that a thread can interrupt *itself* as well, but that obviously would not happen while it's sleeping at the same time.

Also note in your case that `render` adds an ansynchronous invocation of itself through a new `Runnable` to the `EventQueue` recursively, which seems pretty dangerous.

Comment: does render method run in a new runnable that i pass into invokeLater, or in EDT?

Comment: @Zai `render` seems to invoke **itself** in a new thread. So, the first invocation of `render` will sleep for 1 second, then adds a new runnable invoking itself in the system event queue, and so on recursively...

Comment: @Zai in fact, aren't you getting a stack overflow somewhere?

Comment: One problem here is that the OP, like many Java beginners, does not understand what "currently executing thread" means.  The name "current thread" made sense back when computers could  not execute more than one thread at a time, but now that even cell phones have multi-core processors, "current thread" no longer accurately describes what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

> The last thing i don't understand is that when i test this code, by calling Thread.sleep() it interrupts the whole Swing thing: GUI, events etc. That means that everything that is not Swing related in my program should run absolutely seamlessly but seems like it's not.

All UI events in Swing run in a single thread. Usually it is a main thread. If this thread are taken for some activity then whole UI will hang for some time. To avoid hanging do not make heavy calculation in listeners of UI controls.

Comment: Swing events are never handled in the `main()` thread---at least, not in a desktop application.  They are handled in the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).  The EDT is lazily created:  It does not exist until the main() thread (or any other thread) makes a Swing call that needs it.  Typically that happens the first time the program orders a JFrame onto the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Only the Swing main thread or [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) will execute the render method.

If you want that worker threads execute code you must [tell them explicitly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) from the main thread.

```
   SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<ImageIcon[], Void>() {
    @Override
    public ImageIcon[] doInBackground() {
        final ImageIcon[] innerImgs = new ImageIcon[nimgs];
        for (int i = 0; i < nimgs; i++) {
            innerImgs[i] = loadImage(i+1);
        }
        return innerImgs;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        //Remove the "Loading images" label.
        animator.removeAll();
        loopslot = -1;
        try {
            imgs = get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
        catch (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException e) {
            String why = null;
            Throwable cause = e.getCause();
            if (cause != null) {
                why = cause.getMessage();
            } else {
                why = e.getMessage();
            }
            System.err.println("Error retrieving file: " + why);
        }
    }
};
```

For example you could span several SwingWorker and after that sleep the main thread.